# Arrays in recursive print method

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm trying to make a `println` replacement that outputs nested collections in a more readable format. This is best illustrated with an example: I'd like `List(Set(Vector(1.0,1.1), Vector(0d)), Set(Vector("a", "b", "c"), Vector("x", "y")))` to be printed as

```
List
  Set
    Vector(1.0, 1.1)
    Vector(0.0)
  Set
    Vector(a, b, c)
    Vector(x, y)
```

This would be a lot easier without type erasure, but I've come up with

```
def rprint(a: Any, indent: Int = 0): Unit = a match {
  case x: Traversable[_] =>
    if (x.isEmpty)
      rprint(x.toString, indent)
    else x.head match {
      case y: Traversable[_] => {
        rprint(x.toString.takeWhile(_ != '('), indent)
        x foreach {i => rprint(i, indent + 2)}
      }
      case y => rprint(x.toString, indent)
    }
  case x => println(" " * indent + x)
}
```

I'm struggling with getting this to work nicely with Arrays, without substantial code duplication. I'd like them to work the same as for other collections. Specifically:

- Arrays are not `Traversable`
- could convert Arrays using `genericArrayOps` to ArrayOps which is `TraversableOnce`, but `TraversableOnce` doesn't have a `head` method, so I can't see how to get an element to check its type
- `toString` doesn't work quite like other collections (use `.deep`)

What's the best way to incorporate Arrays into this method, or is there a different approach that would work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more flexible I'm defining a trait that includes utility methods and one abstract method, so that it can be used like that `Array(1,2).print`:

```
trait Printable[T] {
  def str(indent: Int = 0): String
  def str: String = str(0)
  def print(indent: Int = 0): Unit = println(str(indent))
  def print: Unit = print(0)
}
```

Then an implicit to make it look like `str` and `print` are methods of `Any`:

```
implicit def any2Printable(a: Any): Printable[Any] = new Printable[Any] {
  import collection._
  def name = a match {
    case a: Array[_] => "Array"
    case g: GenTraversableLike[_, _] => g.stringPrefix 
    case i: Iterator[_] => "Iterator"
    case _ => ""
  }
  object Iter {
    def unapply(a: Any): Option[GenIterable[_]] = a match {
      case a: Array[_] => Some(a.toIterable)
      case t: GenTraversableOnce[_] => Some(t.toIterable)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
  object Nested {
    def unapply(i: GenIterable[_]): Option[GenIterable[_]] = i match {
      case nested if i.exists{case Iter(j) =>true case _ =>false} => Some(nested)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
  def str(indent: Int = 0) = " " * indent + (a match {
    case Iter(i) if i.isEmpty => name + " <empty>"
    case Iter(Nested(i)) => name + "\n" + i.map(_.str(indent+2)).mkString("\n")
    case Iter(i) => name + i.map(_.toString).mkString("(", ", ", ")")
    case _ => a.toString
  })
}
```

This handles arbitrary deep nesting, but won't use multiple lines for collections that don't contain collections - for instance that would print:

```
Array
  Set
    Array(1.0, 1.1)
    Vector <empty>
    Array <empty>
    Set
      Vector(a, b, c)
      Vector(x, y)
      List
        Set
          Array(1.0, 1.1)
          Vector(0.0)
        Set
          Vector(a, b, c)
          Vector(x, y)
```

Comment: This is very cool, and it handles Iterators too, which is great! (I might go now and hack my scala-library.jar to include this in Predef)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting to an ArrayOps, try a [WrappedArray](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.html), which does have a head method and is traversable.

Answer (score 1):

Try tu use more general types in match phrase, like `GenTraversable` to witch exists implicit conversion.

```scala
import scala.collection.GenTraversable

def rprint[T](a: T, indent: Int = 0): Unit = a match {
  case x: String => println(" "*indent + '"' + x + '"')
  case x: GenTraversable[_] =>
    println(" "*indent + (x.stringPrefix))
    x foreach (rprint(_, indent+2))
  case x: Array[_] =>
    println(" "*indent + (a.getClass.getSimpleName))
    x foreach (rprint(_, indent+2))
  case x => println(" "*indent + x)
}

rprint(Map(1->"one",2->"two"))
rprint(List("one", "two"))           //I don't know why this type is printed weird: $colon$colon
rprint(Array(1,2))                   //This prints less weird: int[]
```

You can add more cases for specific missing types (like tuples)

I can't figure what is the problem with printing some type names (like `List` and `Array` - see the example after the function definition). Both `a.getClass.getSimpleName` and `a.ToString` returns wired string

I've also try to connect type `Array` and `GenTraversable` - because there is implicit conversion from  `Array` to `WrapperArray <: GenTraversable`. 
The solution below doesn't satisfy as it prints "WrappedArray" instead "Array", 
when we call the function with `Array` instance

```
case x: Array[_] => rprint(x:GenTraversable[_])
```

Edit:
I've changed name extractor for GenTraversable to `a.stringPrefix`

Comment: This doesn't compile (for me, in REPL, v2.9.0-1) `error: type mismatch; found   : a.type (with underlying type T) required: ?{val getClass: ?}`. I'm looking for display names as in the `toString`, or the `stringPrefix` methods, rather than class names, which can be different (e.g. `List`'s concrete type is `::`).

Comment: I don't know. For me everything goes fine.

Comment: I got it working after upgrading to 2.9.1. I would replace `(a.getClass.getSimpleName)` with simply `"Array"`. This doesn't do quite what's specified since it outputs collection / array elements each on their own line, rather than a string representing the collection (see OP for test case). This is what that makes the problem non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't my intention to answer my own question, but I have something that works. I think it can be improved a lot, so suggestions are appreciated. There is still repetition and a rather ugly cast in there.

```
  def rprint(a: Any, indent: Int = 0): Unit = {
    val (typeStr, fullStr) = a match {
      case x: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[_] => ("Array", x.deep.toString)
      case x: Traversable[_] => (x.stringPrefix, x.toString)
      case _ => ("", "")
    }
    a match {
      case x: Traversable[_] =>
        if (x.isEmpty)
          rprint(typeStr + " <empty>", indent)
        else 
          x.head match {
            case _: Array[_] => {
              rprint(typeStr, indent)
              x foreach {i => rprint(genericWrapArray(
                                       i.asInstanceOf[Array[_]]), indent + 2)}
            }
            case _: Traversable[_] => {
              rprint(typeStr, indent)
              x foreach {i => rprint(i, indent + 2)}
            }
            case _ => rprint(fullStr, indent)
          }
      case x: Array[_] => rprint(genericWrapArray(x))
      case x => println(" " * indent + x)
    }
  }
```

test:

```
scala> rprint(List(Array(Vector(1.0,1.1), Vector(0d)), Array(Array("a", "b", "c"), Array("x", "y"))))
List
  Array
    Vector(1.0, 1.1)
    Vector(0.0)
  Array
    Array(a, b, c)
    Array(x, y)
```